# Custom MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Okie, I am trying to finish a product dispkay for a client, in my code I have this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="itemcontainer">
        <p class="button">@Html.ActionLink(item.Category, item.Category) (@item.Count)</p>
    </div>
}
```

Which gives me the link (URL) of Products/Categories, now what do I need to get to my ultimate goal of (for example) Products/Braceletsss. Do I have to write a custom route, if so can someone show me an example, I'm still trying to get my head around this.

**EDIT*
I can provide more code if it's needed :)

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpGet, Route("products/{categoryName}")]
public IActionResult GetProductsByCategoryName(string categoryName) {
    ... code to retrieve products by category name
```

The above is one way to do it, the way that I prefer at least. When you access the route `/products/nine-millimeter-handguns`, then in your action, the `categoryName` variable will have the value `nine-millimeter-handguns`. You can then use that string value to look up all of the products in that category and return them to the client.

The other way to do it is in your global route config in Startup.cs. If you do it this way, you don't need the `[Route]` attribute on the action method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    ...
    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(null, "products/{categoryName}", new {
            controller = "Products", action = "GetProductsByCategoryName"
        });
    });
}
```

I prefer the former attribute approach because it keeps the routes closer to the controllers & actions that they map to. But both will accomplish the same thing.

In order to render a link to this route from a view, you would pass in the `categoryName` to the ActionLink html helper method:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Category, item.Category, new {
    categoryName = "nine-millimeter-handguns"
})
```

Comment: from `Braceletsss` to `nine-millimeter-handguns`, a perfect end to end solution! :)

Comment: Sorry, I was shopping while answering the question. Don't need any braceletsss.

Comment: @danludwig How about he use a custom htmlhelper? Just throwing an idea

Comment: Whenever I try to use IActionResut it's underlined red and says it cannot be found

Comment: @PsychoCoder make sure you have a `using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;` statement somewhere at the top of the file. If that doesn't compile either, post your project.json please.